# Disable fonts in SharePoint 2010

Tags: css, item-styles

To be able to keep our company style, we would to restrict the usage of different fonts. We would like everyone to use only the Arial font. I was wondering if anyone knows of a simple way to do this. I do not want to edit every page layout on all my sites. The most desired solution is one that requires as few editing/programming as possible.

**Edit** I am aware that there are ways to do this throug editing page layouts, my question is how to do this in a simpler way.

Answer (score 2):

I would look at this article as a starting point. The long an short of it is that you can go ahead and control what uses see in the Rich Text Editor when adding content to a page. Give it a look [Link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mvpawardprogram/archive/2011/05/16/mvps-for-sharepoint-2010-modifying-ribbon-fonts-and-styles-for-publishing-page-html-field-controls.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Paul, this is a good article. However, I already read this article and this includes editing all my page layouts. My question states that i do not want to do this. Is there a way achieve my goal without editing all the page layouts?